# global variables not being updated/ imported properly across modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

in the code below when function `delta` is imported from main.py values of `d1`and `v1`are not being imported properly but when i paste the function `delta` in the same file as function `t` values are imported correctly. why does this happen ? what can i do to get proper values when imported from different file?

```
# stuff.py
from env import v1,d1

def delta ():
   global d1,v1
   gas = d1 + v1
   print (gas)
```

```
#sus.py
from env import d1,v1,idd,m
from main import delta
def t():
    global two
    global d1,v1,idd,m
    two = two -1

    if m ==0:           
     if idd ==1 :
         d1 = 2 
         idd = 0
     elif idd ==0:
          v1 =2
          delta()
          idd =2
```

i did try adding print statements to check value of `d1` and `v1` inside delta and the value is 0 .
and as i have mentioned above the error is  fixed if i place function `delta` in same file as function`t`

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Your line: `from env import d1` just creates a new variable called `d1` which is initialised from the value from the `env` module. Assignments like `d1 = 2` just change the variable in the local module. You should try: `import env` and later: `env.d1 = 2` etc